# LibGDX (OpenGL) Mesh with transparent textures rendering issue

Tags: opengl, libgdx, rendering, z-index, depth-buffer

I have an issue with rendering meshes with transparent vertices in LibGDX.

[chunk on the left not rendering blocks under water properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOYJH.png)

As you can see from the image, some chunk meshes aren't properly rendering blocks under water. What could be the issue here?

These are my OpenGL settings

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Material:

```
        MATERIAL = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture),
            IntAttribute.createCullFace(GL20.GL_FRONT),
            new BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA),
            FloatAttribute.createAlphaTest(0.5f));
```

Comment: Do you render the transparent objects after the opaque objects? 1. Render the opaque objects with the depth test on. 2. render the transparent objects without depth test, from the back to the front.

Comment: NO they are all a single mesh, should opaque objects be a seperate mesh?

Comment: Read the about [Transparency Sorting](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting) respectively [Tutorial 10 : Transparency](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-10-transparency/)

Comment: Yes, transparent and opaque blocks must be in separate meshes for it to render correctly. And transparent faces have to be sorted from far to near in the mesh data.